# React Suspense time limit

Tags: swr, react-suspense, time-limiting

guys! I am relatively new to the concept of Suspense in React so i apologize if the question answer is obvious but i couldn't manage to find similar question asked before.

So i was wondering how can i set/simulate time limit for Suspense. Assuming i am having an API that returns a simple JSON after a 5 seconds dalay and i want Suspense to wait for 3s max then show some kind of ErrorComponent 'Time limit exceeded'?

Just to mention - i am fetching the data using SWR.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to use `loadingTimeout` option and `onLoadingSlow` callback, but for some reason it does not fire when `suspense: true`. Maybe it is a bug.

Another possible solution is to use something like `axios` to fetch the data, it has `timeout` option so you can specify this time limit after which axios will throw an error. Don't forget to disable swrs `shouldRetryOnError` option.

```
  const { data } = useSWR(
    `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${post}`,
    // Use whatever timeout you need
    (url) => axios.get(url, { timeout: 5000 }),
    {
      suspense: true,
      shouldRetryOnError: false
    }
  );
```

[image: Edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73224251]

Comment: Axios did great. Thank you very much!